# Issue with shopify and iframe

Tags: html, iframe, shopify

I want to add iframe to my shopify page without success!

How to solve it ?

They want me to write "http**s**" instead of "http" !

If I do so the links well be dead !

I tried doing Video form youtube it works only with "http**s**"

Maybe I have to do it with WordPress and integrate shopify later.

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfS8g.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you sure you meant to say *without* success?

Comment: Also, make sure you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Ms.Nehal thank you and sorry for that :)

Comment: @tmthydvnprt thanks I'll details

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this is that your Shopify page is secured by ssl certificate. When a page is delivered over https you will get errors when integrating elements which are not secure.

So add a ssl certificate to your website you want to include in an iframe and use it with https.

Comment: thanks but according to shopify : SSL certificates are activated by default in Shopify for your store's checkout

Comment: The problem is not the ssl certificate of Shopify, it's more the non-available one of the website you want to integrate as an iframe.